# yiic shell does not launch on OS X

Tags: php, macos, shell, yii, yiic

I'm a rails developer returning to do a bit of PHP after many years in the rubyland. I've landed a `Yii` based project that I'm trying to get grips of and have run into an issue of not being able to run the yiic shell.

Please see below:

```
mymachine:protected randomm$ ./yiic shell
/Users/randomm/git/myproject/protected/config/main.php 
mymachine:protected randomm$
```

i.e. it does nothing, just returns the prompt immediately. This is on `OS X Mavericks`.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Have gotten used to being able to run stuff inside the rails console and being able to do the same with `yii` would be fantastic!

Comment: Probably a permission issue.Check `../protected> ls -al yiic `  and make if its not executable make it executable by `sudo chmod +x yiic` . In other case php.ini for php-cli  is not set properly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but yiic is executable, and I seem to be able to run PHP cli fine: `mymachine:protected randomm$ which php
/usr/bin/php
mymachine:protected randomm$ php -v
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
mymachine:protected randomm$`